# django m2m_changed signal with custom through model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I am trying to use the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) to trigger some actions in my application
. However, the printout of `signaltest()` indicates that I am only signalled on `pre_clear` and `post_clear` actions. My `models.py` looks like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    objects = managers.MyEntryManager()
    ...
    fields = models.ManyToManyField('Field', through='EntryField')

class Field(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)

class EntryField(models.Model):
    entry = models.ForeignKey('Entry')
    field = models.ForeignKey('Field')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=256)

def signaltest(**kwargs):
    print kwargs['action']
signals.m2m_changed.connect(signaltest, sender=Entry.fields.through, weak=False, dispatch_uid='signaltest')
```

The `EntryField` objects are created elsewhere in the code using the following code:

```
some_entry.fields.clear()
models.EntryField.objects.get_or_create(
    entry=some_entry,
    field=some_field,
    defaults = { 'value': field_value }
)
```

The first call is responsible for the `pre_clear` and `post_clear` events I receive. However, the second call generates no signals.

It seems to me that [django bug #13757](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13757) is related to this (mis)behaviour, but I may be missing something.

Is there a way to "rewire" the signals (perhaps using some signal other than `m2m_changed`) to have `post_save` signals generated when a `EntryField` is created?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't connect your signal handler to post_save?

Comment: `m2m_changed` just looked more suitable. I wouldn't mind using `post_save` signal if I had an explanation for the following behaviour: I get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when connecting to `post_save` and printing `kwargs`. The error is generated at the time `kwargs['instance']` is printed. Curiously, if I just use `kwargs['instance']` without printing it, there are no problems. This makes me a bit sceptical on whether `post_save` should be used in this way.

Comment: @ChrisLawlor Ok. I solved the `TypeError` issue. It was my fault after all - had missed a `%` in the implementation of `EntryField.__unicode__` (not shown above). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this out?

```
def signaltest(**kwargs):
   print kwargs['instance']
   print kwargs['created']

signals.post_save.connect(signaltest, sender=EntryField, weak=False, dispatch_uid='signaltest')
```

Comment: The `action` argument is specific to `m2m_changed` signal. So, your snippet (which connects to `post_save` signal) throws an exception. Are you sure you haven't mistyped anything?